Python generic type on function getting lost somewhere
Getting this typing error:
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "object", variable has type "A | B")  [assignment]

With this code:
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import TypeVar, Mapping, reveal_type


@dataclass
class A:
    foo: str = "a"

@dataclass
class B:
    bar: str = "b"

lookup_table: Mapping[str, type[A] | type[B]] = {
    "a": A,
    "b": B
}

reveal_type(lookup_table)  # note: Revealed type is "typing.Mapping[builtins.str, Union[type[simple.A], type[simple.B]]]"
T = TypeVar("T")

def load(lookup_table: Mapping[str, type[T]], lookup_key:str) -> T:
    con: type[T] = lookup_table[lookup_key]
    instance: T = con()
    return instance

example_a: A | B = load(lookup_table, "a")  # error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "object", variable has type "A | B")
print(example_a)


Edit: Logged a mypy bug here: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/18265

It looks like mypy is distributing type[Either] across the union, producing a union of type[A] and type[B], and then failing to recognize that this union can be matched against type[T]. I don't know the mypy internals well enough to be sure this is what's going on, though.

In any case, this looks like a flaw in mypy. I don't know if it's already been reported, but if it hasn't, it deserves a report.

These should return the same, right? print(Union[A|B]) print(Either) . Instead: typing.Union[__main__.A, __main__.B] __main__.A | __main__.B  so Either = A | B does not define Union[A|B]

@LMC: typing.Union is supposed to be semantically equivalent to unions with |, but it's not quite the same thing at runtime - | uses the very similar types.UnionType, rather than typing.Union. types.UnionType and typing.Union print differently.

In any case, nothing here actually uses typing.Union, so typing.Union is irrelevant.

From PEP 604: With this new operator, it is possible to write int | str instead of Union[int, str]. print(Union[A,B]) typing.Union[__main__.A, __main__.B]

@LMC: They're semantically equivalent, but they don't have the same runtime implementation. The difference has nothing to do with the issue at hand.

Shouldn't Mapping[str, type[Either]] be the same as Mapping[str, type[Union[A,B]]]?

@LMC: In every way except the minor types.UnionType/typing.Union difference, they are the same. And if you replace Mapping[str, type[Either]] with Mapping[str, type[Union[A,B]]], you get the exact same mypy error. The difference between | and Union doesn't affect anything here.

Got no errors with Mapping[str, type[Union[A,B]]] or Mapping[str, type[A|B]] on python 3.11

@LMC: That's because you're running the code, not type-checking it. Python doesn't enforce type hints at runtime. x: int = 'five' runs fine, despite having a clearly invalid type annotation. You need to type-check it with mypy.

Yes, it's a bug, and a tough one. You're correct about type[A|B] distribution: mypy first reinterprets it as type[A] | type[B] and then tries to solve type[T] ~ type[A] | type[B]. mypy solves this as an intersection (to confirm, if A and B have a common parent narrower than object, it's inferred instead). The comments about union syntax are all irrelevant. basedmypy uses unions, and code checks with basedmypy as expected (you can select it in the playground above).

FWIW this produces no errors with pyright version 1.1.390

Logged a mypy bug here: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/18265

This is a mypy bug present in 1.13.0 and below (previously reported here and by OP here). pyright and basedmypy both accept the given snippet.
mypy stores type[A | B] types as a union of types internally (type[A] | type[B]). This is usually convenient, but causes troubles when solving type[T] <: type[A] | type[B] for T, because most types aren't "distributive" (P[A, B] is not equivalent to P[A] | P[B]), and type special case isn't taken into account yet.
General solver produces meet(A, B) in such case by solving
type[T] <: type[A]  =>  T <: A  |
                                |  =>  T <: meet(A, B)
type[T] <: type[B]  =>  T <: B  |

When A and B have no explicit parent in common, the closest supertype is object. To understand the logic behind that, consider similar equations: x < 2 && x < 3 => x < min(2, 3), and intersection/meet is for types what min operation is for numbers (and union/join is similar to max).
I submitted a PR to special-case this behaviour, so things may change in a future mypy release.

Amazing. You are a hero.

The error occurs because the load function is returning either (A|B) which is not detected by the type checker in that function, as it was expecting an object . Therefore, it is giving an error of incompatible types.
